# Citing a project performed in a previous class that was never published?

Tags: publications, citations

In a past class I completed a project whose results and methods will prove useful in my current class project. This project, written in a journal style format, was never published, and will most likely never be published.

How do I go about properly citing this project? Should I simply list the title, college, and date? What is the accepted format?

Comment: I'd include in the citation not only title, college, and date --- and of course author --- but also some additional information to indicate what sort of document this is. So I'd probably indicate that it was a project for such-and-such class, taught by so-and-so. I might also give the number of pages.  (I won't say anything about how to format all this, because I've never paid much attention to citation styles.)

Comment: Put a copy of the old project report on the web, and then include the URL with the other bibliographic information.

Answer (score 1):

You could publish it as a preprint. Or if you want to publish some specific section you could use some dedicated service that provides with with a doi, e.g. you can use protocols.io for your protocol or figshare/zenodo for your dataset. This way not only are citable but it will have a unique identifier.